# Does the same site cookie policy potentially change anything for CORS

Tags: security, browsers, cookie, cross-origin

According to the new same-site cookie policy (once implemented across all browsers) , a third party call from another page would not send along the cookies by default, unless the third party explicitly indicates that by setting appropriate cookie metadata.

As per my understanding, this would help with CSRF prevention. Does it cover all cases for CSRF ? Can this policy obsolete  the same-origin policy since it seems to solve the same problems, or does the same origin policy cover other use cases?
Does this potentially  mean that we wouldn't need CORS setup on the servers anymore?